# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module with firebase

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a firebase project, although I don't know why it dosen't work.

I want to use a firebase functions created in function/index.js :

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.fullName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const firstName = data.firstName;
  const lastName = data.lastName;
  return {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    fullName: firstName + " " + lastName,
  };
});
```

therfore i call it from public/script.js :

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFunctions,httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: X
  authDomain:X 
  databaseURL: X
  projectId: X
  storageBucket: X
  messagingSenderId:X
  appId: X
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const functions = getFunctions(app);

function addName() {
  var _firstName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
  var _lastName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
  const fullName = functions.httpsCallable(functions, 'fullName');
//For the fullName we have defined that fullName takes some data as a parameter 
  fullName({firstName: _firstName,
            lastName: _lastName
            })
    .then((result)=> {
        console.log(result);
        const data = result.data
    }).catch((error)=> {
        console.log(error);   
    })
    reception(data)
}
function reception(data){
  output = document.getElementById("out")
  output.value = data.fullName
}
```

and this script.js is called by public/index.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src ="/script.js"></script>
      <script>

         function addName() {
            var _firstName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
            var _lastName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
            const fullName = functions.httpsCallable(functions, 'fullName');
      //For the fullName we have defined that fullName takes some data as a parameter 
            fullName({firstName: _firstName,
                      lastName: _lastName
                      })
              .then((result)=> {
                  console.log(result);
                  const data = result.data
              }).catch((error)=> {
                  console.log(error);   
              })
              reception(data)
          }
          function reception(data){
            output = document.getElementById("out")
            output.value = data.fullName
          }
       </script>
</head>
<body>
       <input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="First Name">
       <input type="text" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name">
       <button onClick="addName()"> Add Name </button>
       <textarea id = "out"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i deploy it, it seams to work but I got the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

but then when I change

```
<script src ="/script.js"></script>
```

for

```
<script type = "module" src ="/script.js"></script>
```

another error occurs : addName is not defined. or when i put addName definition in another  bloc, functions is not defined or httpsCallable either. I suppose that it don't load the modules and therefore it cannot run the script.

I also had :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` before but without changing anything the error message vanished.

I use firebase v9 and I followed the firebase website's tutorial but I didn't find the answer to my problem

I want this code to work in order to understand how google functions works.

thank you for reading all of this ^^

[Here is how my project is built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htQBk.png)
(sorry I don't know how to put it like a tree)

Comment: Using `onClick` is a no-no, you should use `addEventListenr` it would resolve your issues

Comment: How do you build your project?

Comment: Indeed onClick was an issue, thank you about that, but now I have the module import issue and get the errors   :  (index):23 Uncaught ReferenceError: functions is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.addName AND Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at script.js:2:1)

Comment: and if I put the type = "module" for the script.jvs in the html file, i get this : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". but I don't know why

Comment: Do you use webpack?

Comment: No I don't use webpack. Should I import it ? and How can I import it ?

Comment: You have to build your project to use libraries from npm

Comment: I have managed to use webpack although I have multiple errors : Could not load content for webpack://node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js.map: Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: And also :  functions.httpsCallable is not a function

Comment: Have you tried inputting the `"type": "module"` in `package.json`?